# PhD Supervisor Jekyll/Hyde

Tags: advisor

I have a Phd supervisor who yo-yos between being overly critical and mean and then thoughtful and kind. I find it very confusing, as it's so inconsistent. I would hope that I am a good judge of character, but I don't know if he has the best intentions for me. I don't know if I should ask him  to be a reference for post-doc positions. What are some ways that you have handled working with your superiors who behave in this way?

Comment: Can you give examples for both kinds of behaviour? Perception and evaluation of behaviour can be very subjective, so it's hard to get a clear picture of the situation from the current content of your question.

Comment: In academia many share a value system that implies that you should be nice and caring to other persons and particularly your PhD students  but hard and critical when it comes to their work, as this is the best to ensure high quality. From the outside it is not always obvious to see when is the time for what. It may well be that the supervisor's value system leads to the kind of behaviour described by you.

Comment: How often is this yo-yo? In the same meeting?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps he has mental issues. It isn't unknown in academia. Perhaps he is going through something personal that is affecting his general behavior.

You might talk to someone else on the faculty (or another student, perhaps) who can give you some advice. The head is probably aware of such things and you can seek advice there, though don't make it a complaint.

An untenured advisor might be frantic about their own tenure case and behave inconsistently. And, "critical" can be different from "mean". Personally critical is not acceptable, of course.

Comment: "Personally critical is not acceptable, of course." Depends on what they're criticising the person for. If it's something like unprofessional behaviour or appearance, then that might be acceptable.

Comment: @nick012000, I wouldn't call that "personal", though.